# PIL Image list into a video slide with cv2.VideoWriter

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm created the follow function.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

FPS = 10

def write_video(file_name, images, slide_time=5):
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'X264')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, FPS, (870, 580))

    for image in images:
        cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        for _ in range(slide_time * FPS):
            out.write(cv_img)

    out.release()
```

It worked once, but I broke it, don't know how.

When I try to open with MPV I get:

```
[ffmpeg/demuxer] avi: Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (X264 / 0x34363258), none, 870x580): unspecified pixel format
[ffmpeg/demuxer] Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
 (+) Video --vid=1 (h264 870x580 10.000fps)


Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
import numpy as np



FPS = 10

res = requests.get('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.bNvIoWPYwYWXe-gpRKsalQHaE9%26pid%3DApi&f=1')

image = Image.open(BytesIO(res.content))
image = np.array(image)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'MJPG')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, FPS, (870, 580))


for _ in range(13 * FPS):
    video.write(image)

video.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address the issues with your code.

- Issue#1:

---

- The error says:

  > Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264"

  - Means `x264` codec is not available in your current environment.
  - You either install `opencv-python` or
  - Initialize the codec as `MJPG` (Motion-JPEG). The reason is `MJPG` is suitable with the `.avi` files.
  - ```py
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'MJPG')
    ```
- Issue#2:

---

- You are converting from `RGB` to `BGR`
- I suggest read image, so you don't have to convert to the `BGR`.
- `cv2.imread` reads the image in `BGR` format
- Also make sure each image is the same size with the defined `VideoCapture` size.

  - ```py
    for image in images:
        cv_img = cv2.imread(image)
        cv_img = cv2.resize(cv_img, (870, 580))
    ```

Code is updated based on the min-reproducible error:

---

```py
import cv2
from glob import glob

FPS = 10


def write_video(file_name, images, slide_time=5):
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'MJPG')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, fourcc, FPS, (870, 580))

    for image in images:
        cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        for _ in range(slide_time * FPS):
            cv_img = cv2.resize(image, (870, 580))
            out.write(cv_img)

    out.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_video(file_name='result.avi', images=glob("b/*.jpg"))
```

Comment: images are PIL Images instances. I wouldn't like to save the images into disk. I've tried with MJPG before, just tried again, same error. It worked once before, have no ideia what I've changed that now it don't work anymore.

Comment: If they are PIL image instances, why you are not using `cv_img = Image.open(image)`? I mean, you have to read images using either `Image.open` or `cv2.imread`. Otherwise you are passing the image path as a parameter.

Comment: No, the images are responses from requests. I place the response content into a BytesIO and open it with PIL. `Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))`

Comment: I'm confused, how `Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))` is related with the `for image in images:`. So each `image` is not a path like `C:..\\..\\MyPic\\...\\.png`?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I read create a Image instance from the the get response. It is like image open from file as I can call `.show()` it displays the same way. images is a array of PIL Image.

Comment: You may try the follow to understand `Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.bNvIoWPYwYWXe-gpRKsalQHaE9%26pid%3DApi&f=1').content)).show()`

Comment: I've add a standalone example.

Comment: So you have multiple url's and when you are reading using `request` you will have a problem. Am I now correct? or am I still missing?

Comment: I think what you are missing just resize your images with the same size with the `VideoWriter` size. For instance: `image = cv2.resize(image, (870, 580))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223541/discussion-between-wviana-and-ahx).